# Multi dimensional array merge using php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge two arrays

eg:

```
Array( [menu_id] =>1, 
            [functions] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => AE,
                     [1] => AR
                 )) 
     Array( [menu_id] =>2, 
            [functions] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => AE,
                     [1] => AR
                 )


            )
```

I need to merge these tow arrays. I have 2 sub menu under each main menu.based on user selection I need to add for main menu what and all sub menus are added

[image]

this is a sample picture of my work

here is my code but its not working.

```
  if(isset($_POST['add_menu1']))
                    { 
                        $arrayOrgPri = array("id"=>"1","functions"=>array("AE"));                    
                    }
    if(isset($_POST['app_menu1']))
                    {
                        $newarry =  array("id"=>"1","functions"=>array("AR"));
                        $arrayPrivilege =  array_merge_recursive($arrayOrgPri,$newarry);
                    }

                    if(isset($_POST['add_menu2']))
                    { 
                        $newarry =  array("id"=>"2","functions"=>array("AE"));
                        $arrayPrivilege =array_merge_recursive($arrayPrivilege,$newarry);                   
                    }
                    if(isset($_POST['app_menu2']))
                    {
                        $newarry =  array("id"=>"2","functions"=>array("AR"));
                        $arrayPrivilege = array_merge_recursive($arrayPrivilege,$newarry);
                    }
```

I want an output like this

```
 Array
            (
                [menu_id] =>1, 
                [functions] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => AE,
                     [1] => AR
                 ),
                [menu_id] =>2, 
                [functions] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => AE,
                     [1] => AR
                 )

            )
```

but this code output is

```
Array
(
    [menu_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
        )

    [functions] => Array
        (
            [0] => AE
            [1] => AR
            [2] => AE
            [3] => AR
        )

)
```

How i can implement this using php
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create two separate arrays and combine both here is the solution

```
 if(isset($_POST['add_menu1']))
                    { 
                        $arrayOrgPri = array("id"=>"1","functions"=>array("AE"));                    
                    }
    if(isset($_POST['app_menu1']))
                    {
                        $newarry =  array("functions"=>array("AR"));
                        $arrayOrgPri =  array_merge_recursive($arrayOrgPri,$newarry);
                    }

                    if(isset($_POST['add_menu2']))
                    { 
                        $arrayPrivilege =  array("id"=>"2","functions"=>array("AE"));

                    }
                    if(isset($_POST['app_menu2']))
                    {
                        $newarry =  array("functions"=>array("AR"));
                        $arrayPrivilege = array_merge_recursive($arrayPrivilege,$newarry);
                    }
                    $combinearray = array($arrayOrgPri,$arrayPrivilege);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want multiple array elements with the same keys. It's not possible. Try the following structure instead:

`
    $menu = array(

```
[1] => array(


    [0] => AE,


    [1] => AR,


),


[2] => array(


    [0] => AE,


    [1] => AR,


),


[another_menu_I'd] => array_with_functions
```

`